# SSRS 2008 R2 CountRows(GroupName) doesn't work

Tags: ssrs-2008

I created a report for SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Service, in design mode this report looks like :

[image]

You can see I have an expression in the left cell of second row from last, the expression is:

```
=CountRows("GroupbyClassification")
```

When I preview this report, it give me this error:

```
The value expression for the textbox ‘textbox7’ has a scope parameter that is not valid
for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is
equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or 
the name of a data set
```

This error is caused by CountRows("GroupbyClassification"), from

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255215(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255215%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can see CountRows can work on a group. But why it doesn't work for me. If I just use CountRows(), it at least works without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `GroupbyClassification` isn't the current or containing scope. It is the child scope. If you use `=CountRows("GroupbyLocation")`, it will give you the same results as `=CountRows()` because `GroupbyLocation` is the current scope. Since there are multiple `GroupbyClassification` Row Count values for each `GroupbyLocation` group, the report can't know which one to return when you specify the `GroupbyClassification` scope.

Child scopes can only be used in nested aggregates. So, you could use `=sum(CountRows("GroupbyClassification"))`, but that would give you the same counts as `=CountRows("GroupbyLocation")` and `=CountRows()`.